# Is there a generic way of setting field values in mapper from list of values?

Tags: lift, mapper

Is there a way of creating  method for setting the value in the Model's fields **without** setting the values explicitly like -

`ModelName.create.fieldName1("value").fieldName2("value2") and so on`

Can we iterate through all available fields of that model and set their values form some list-of-values ?

something like ...

`Model.allFields.foreach((fld)=> {

                                                                                                          fld.set(valueList(indx)); indx+=1

}`

Actually I want to set values into all models using some generic method that works for all models.

Comment: Looking at http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M5/#net.liftweb.record.Record and http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M5/#net.liftweb.record.Field suggests that it is possible. Also scala List.zip function may helps you to avoid increase index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my comment:

```
val list = List(...)
val record = YourRecordClass.createRecord
record.allFields.zip(list).foreach {case(field,value) => field.setFromAny(value)}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, But I was not able to find .setFromAny in my case. Are you using Record instead of mapper ?

Comment: No issues, I managed it using the .set(value.asInstanceOf[value.ValueType]).